# Directory Stacks with Python

Tags: python, stack

I implemented basic `pushd` and `popd` functionality for a Python script. What's a more academic/formal way to implement a directory stack?

```py
_directory_stack = {0:getcwd()}

def pushd(target: str):
    """Push a new directory to the top of the stack and changes to it.

    Arguments:
        target {str} -- Where you want to go
    """
    highest_seen = max(_directory_stack.keys())
    _directory_stack[highest_seen+1] = target
    chdir(target)

def popd():
    """Pops the most recent directory off the stop of the stack and returns you to the previous directory
    """
    current_top = max(_directory_stack.keys())
    _directory_stack.pop(current_top, None)
    chdir(_directory_stack[current_top-1])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Academic/formal* is not what's needed here. *Simple* is what's needed.

A dict whose keys are all integers from 0 to n is suspicious. Why not use a list instead? You can add items to the end with `.append` and remove them with `.pop`. Then you don't have to bother with `max(_directory_stack.keys())`.

This is the usual way to implement a stack in Python.

Edit: oh, wait, here's an academic/formal issue: `popd` doesn't restore correctly with relative paths. For example:

```
pushd('foo')
pushd('bar')
popd()
```

Should the directory now be `foo` or `foo/bar/foo`?

There are two ways to fix this:

1. `pushd` can convert the path to an absolute path with `os.path.abspath`.
2. Instead of saving the directory it's changing to, `pushd` can save the current directory (`getcwd`), and `popd` can just `chdir` to whatever it popped.

Which one to do depends on where you want to restore to if someone changes the directory without telling `pushd`. Consider this sequence:

```
pushd('/foo')
chdir('bar')
pushd('/baz')
popd()
```

Should the directory now be `/foo` or `/foo/bar`?

Comment: I liked this. I ended up going with your recommendations. Thanks! https://gist.github.com/mxplusb/c895b90d1df65f1e741267d395b3e674

Comment: If you post that version as a new question, you can get someone else to review it. (There's some unnecessary complexity.)